# Duplicate JARs are getting copied though excluded in pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-dependency

I am trying to add `jdom 2.0.2` dependency in one of my project.In order to do that I added following entry in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

But after building the project I found that both `jdom 1.0` and `jdom 2.0.2` got copied. Then I ran `mvn dependency:tree`
command which shows that `jdom 1.0` jars are coming from `jaxen 1.1` dependency through transitive dependency. 
To exclude that dependency I added an exclusions in jaxen dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
          <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

But still I am facing same issue. Both(jdom 1.0 and 2.0.2) jars are getting copied. `mvn dependency:tree` also is showing the same result

```
INFO] +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1:compile
INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
INFO] |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
```

Could you please help on this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look carefully at the dependency output:

```
INFO] +- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1:compile
INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
INFO] |  +- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
```

The group ID for the `jdom` dependency is just `jdom`, not `org.jdom`. Fix the exclusion and that should do it.

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```